# Have someone tried to implement a private ethereum network based on BaaS of Microsoft & azure servers or some other companies?

Tags: private-blockchain, dapps, microsoft-azure, blockchain-as-a-service

I'm creating/implementing a private ethereum network for a group of friends to "play with" the blockchain, develop dapps on top of it.

during my google searches, I found the "blockchain as a service" offer from Microsoft that's basically presented as the AWS of the blockchain with some ready to use environment.

can I get some feedback on that? what are your "go-to" if you wanted to create a private ethereum blockchain?

What is the minimum required hardware to run a private network (how many servers? minimum CPU, RAM, Hard disk etc etc)?

EDIT:
to make things clear : I want to create a private ethereum network, implement/develop a dapp on top of that ethereum private ecosystem and let people/clients access to it and use it.

I'm asking about the BaaS and the minimum hardware requirement because I want the network and the platform to be as much professional as possible and as much stable as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a private chain then you don't need any blockchain as a service solutions.  You can follow the [documentation here](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/test-networks.html#id3) from Ethereum and stand up a private ethereum network relatively easily.  There are lots of tutorial walkthroughs on how to do this.

I have deployed Ethereum using Microsoft Azure and created a whole ethereum based blockchain solution with miners, transactions nodes and 1trillion ETH.  Here is the video I made walking you through the deployment.  The actual deployment takes about 12 mins towards the end if you want to skip right to it otherwise you will have to listen to me explain everything along the way.

[Video](https://youtu.be/HsConsFaZG8)

I also have a private network running in AWS with 2 instances running.  These are two simple geth nodes created with custom genesis file.

For testing a private chain you can get away with one virtual machine, 2GB and dual core.  For a usable private chain at least 2 servers/virtual machines.

As much hard disk space as you can give it as the blockchain will grow over time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The thing is I want to create a private ethereum network, implement/develop a dapp on top of that ethereum private ecosystem and let people/clients access to it and use it.

I'm asking about the BaaS and the minimum hardware requirement because I want the network and the platform to be as much professional as possible and as much stable as possible

Comment: I have added more to the answer, if it helps and answers your question can you please accept the answer.